# How to type IPA quickly on Mac?

Tags: ipa, software, tools

I want shortcuts (pre-existing or customised) for IPA symbols.
I've installed IPA Unicode keyboard, which works fine on notes/ google docs but not on pages. I don't have ms word.
Keyman does not come with a list of shortcuts I can refer to and learn.
I don't want to have to Fn+E and look up the symbols menu to manually pick each symbol.
(For reference, I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.6.9)

Comment: IPA Unicode seems to work fine for me in Pages 13.1 in Monterey.  What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: A list of shortcuts for Keyman can be found at https://help.keyman.com/keyboard/sil_ipa/1.8.6/sil_ipa

Comment: @TomGewecke pages 13.1 refuses to switch to IPA unicode as input source. It makes the switch to every other keyboard just fine.

Comment: Try reinstalling Pages and iPA Unicode.  It works fine for me, and an input source like that should work in any apple app.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is not about computer programs.

Answer (score 0):

Is pasting text from an IPA keyboard webpage acceptable? There is a popular IPA keyboard here: https://ipa.typeit.org/full/

The website allows you to type in IPA fairly quickly through keyboard shortcuts and copy it to the clipboard.

[fɹ̈ ɘgˈzɛə̯̃mpɫ̩ | ˈhi̠ɹ̈ ɘz ə nɛ̝ɹ̈o̜ʊ̯ tʃɹ̥̈ɛə̯̃nˈskɹ̈ɪ̞pʃn̩ ɐɪ̯ ˈme̞ɪ̯d̪ ˌðɛ̝ɹ̈]

Comment: "I don't want to have to Fn+E and look up the symbols menu to manually pick each symbol"